# How to integrate this formula with secant, exponential, and tangent?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate this?

$$\int \sec^2(3x)\ e^{\large\tan (3x)}\ dx$$

Comment: Try setting $\tan(3x)=u$

Comment: Set $$u=e^{\tan{3x}}$$

Comment: By trying yourself.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int e^{\tan(3x)} \underbrace{\Big( \sec^2(3x)\,dx \Big)}_{\text{HINT}}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(\tan 3x)'=3\sec^23x\implies\int\sec^23x\,e^{\tan3x}dx=$$

$$=\frac13\int (\tan3x)'e^{\tan3x}dx=\frac13e^{\tan3x}+C.$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $u=\tan 3x$ and $du=3\sec^23x\ dx$, then
$$
\int\sec^23x\ e^{\large\tan 3x}\ dx=\frac13\int e^u\ du.
$$